# Why is Automator crashing on launch?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, crash, automator

I've run into an odd problem where Automtor.app on Snow Leopard crashes on launch. At some point in the past, I put a copy of iPhoto.app into my public directory to copy over to another machine. Now, Automator.app won't run unless my public directory has a copy of iPhoto.app in it. If I remove it, Automator.app crashes on launch.

Here's what happens:

1. Launch Automator.app
2. After the Automator menu bar appears, but before any windows appear, I get the dreaded beach ball for a few seconds
3. Automator crashes

Here's the output from Console.app:

```
12/26/09 2:11:24 PM Automator[11736]    The action “Add Movie to iDVD Menu” could not be loaded because the application “iDVD” was not found.
12/26/09 2:11:24 PM Automator[11736]    The action “Get iDVD Slideshow Images” could not be loaded because the application “iDVD” was not found.
12/26/09 2:11:24 PM Automator[11736]    The action “Initiate Remote Broadcast” could not be loaded because the application “QuickTime Broadcaster” was not found.
12/26/09 2:11:24 PM Automator[11736]    The action “New iDVD Menu” could not be loaded because the application “iDVD” was not found.
12/26/09 2:11:24 PM Automator[11736]    The action “New iDVD Movie Sequence” could not be loaded because the application “iDVD” was not found.
12/26/09 2:11:24 PM Automator[11736]    The action “New iDVD Slideshow” could not be loaded because the application “iDVD” was not found.
12/26/09 2:11:24 PM Automator[11736]    The action “New QuickTime Slideshow” could not be loaded because the application “QuickTime Player” was not found.
12/26/09 2:11:24 PM Automator[11736]    The action “Set iDVD Background Image” could not be loaded because the application “iDVD” was not found.
12/26/09 2:11:24 PM Automator[11736]    The action “Set iDVD Button Face” could not be loaded because the application “iDVD” was not found.
12/26/09 2:11:24 PM Automator[11736]    The action “Set Movie Annotations” could not be loaded because the application “QuickTime Player” was not found.
12/26/09 2:11:24 PM Automator[11736]    The action “Set Movie Playback Properties” could not be loaded because the application “QuickTime Player” was not found.
12/26/09 2:11:24 PM Automator[11736]    The action “Set Movie URL” could not be loaded because the application “QuickTime Player” was not found.
12/26/09 2:11:24 PM Automator[11736]    The action “Show Main iDVD Menu” could not be loaded because the application “iDVD” was not found.
12/26/09 2:11:25 PM Automator[11736]    Can not ID UTI for path The value %@ is invalid.: The file “The value %@ is invalid.” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
12/26/09 2:11:25 PM Automator[11736]    Can not ID UTI for path /Users/brimhall/Public/iPhoto.app: The file “iPhoto.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
12/26/09 2:11:25 PM Automator[11736]    Can not ID UTI for path The value %@ is invalid.: The file “The value %@ is invalid.” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
12/26/09 2:11:26 PM Automator[11736]    -[NSAttributeDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x49c770
12/26/09 2:11:26 PM Automator[11736]    -[NSAttributeDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x49c770
12/26/09 2:11:38 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[203]  ([0x0-0x2ad2ad].com.apple.Automator[11736]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault
```

I've tried deleting my Automator.app Preferences file and Application Support directory to get it to look for iPhoto.app in the system-wide Applications directory, but to no avail. Any suggestions on how I can get things working as normal?

Answer (score 1):

This matter was solved over at the [Apple discussion boards](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2277230&tstart=0).

Basically, re-re-re-re-deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Automator.plist` *and then deleting my user actions* (`~/Library/Automator/*.action`) did the trick.